# How to codesign a shell script executable inside a Mac app bundle?

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, codesign

I have an executable shell script under `myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/`. Our code-sign pipeline complains that the subcomponent (this script) is not signed.

How should I sign it? Our current pipeline has `codesign --sign` calls with hardcoded certificate numbers and field details I don't quite get. Basically only the app and some plugin bundles inside the app got code-signed.

I cannot find dedicated documentation on how to code-sign shell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW...late answer...however, it may help someone: if you have designated (through `Info.plist's CFBundleExecutable` key's value) the script to be your app's executable, by the time you attempt to sign said script, you should make sure everything else has already been signed.

Note: this is my experience using `codesign` through a bash script (so, not using `XCode`). Apple's docs say that you should sign your app bundle "from inside out"; this was my interpretation and it seems to work just fine for us.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to the following shell script in the Build Phases > Run Script section of your project settings should work...

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer" --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME.app/Frameworks/$framework
```